# Merge [high-traffic] into [high-load]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

Please merge [high-traffic](/questions/tagged/high-traffic) (24) into [high-load](/questions/tagged/high-load) (67).

Comment: Don't just list tags and say "merge these"; explain _why_ you think the tags should be synonyms.

Answer (score 16):

No, please don't.

They mean different things.

You can easily have a high load on a machine that has low to zero traffic.

Comment: From my point of view, very often that's the same things. On _programming_ Q&A site the difference makes no sense, absolutely.